# g++: error: obj/Debug/main.o: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, codeblocks

Running my C++ project at CodeBlocks. And build error occured when trying to use openCV. I added compiler and linker flags as follows

`` -Wall `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -std=c++11 –c ``

`` -Wall `pkg-config --libs opencv` -std=c++11 -lpigpio -lrt -lpthread ``

```
//Here are the headers in my code:


#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "pigpio.h"

int main()
{
    ...
}



//And here is the build log:

-------------- Build: Debug in main (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

g++ -Wall -fexceptions -g -Wall -I/usr/include/opencv -std=c++11 –c  -c /home/pi/Desktop/CodeBlocks4/main/main.cpp -o obj/Debug/main.o
g++  -o bin/Debug/main obj/Debug/main.o  -Wall -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_aruco -lopencv_bgsegm -lopencv_bioinspired -lopencv_ccalib -lopencv_datasets -lopencv_dpm -lopencv_face -lopencv_freetype -lopencv_fuzzy -lopencv_hdf -lopencv_line_descriptor -lopencv_optflow -lopencv_video -lopencv_plot -lopencv_reg -lopencv_saliency -lopencv_stereo -lopencv_structured_light -lopencv_phase_unwrapping -lopencv_rgbd -lopencv_viz -lopencv_surface_matching -lopencv_text -lopencv_ximgproc -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_xobjdetect -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_ml -lopencv_xphoto -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_photo -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core -std=c++11 -lpigpio -lrt -lpthread  
g++: error: obj/Debug/main.o: No such file or directory
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

Comment: For a simple Hello World program, CodeBlocks works? The program compiles?

Comment: An observation: Look at this compile command `g++ -Wall -fexceptions -g -Wall -I/usr/include/opencv -std=c++11 –c  -c /home/pi/Desktop/CodeBlocks4/main/main.cpp -o obj/Debug/main.o`. There are same flags appearing twice here. I believe that some of the flags are automatically set from the Tools/Options and/or Tools/Compilers menu options so you don't have to repeat those yourself such as `-c`. You need to look at those options.

Comment: thanks, i removed -c and it works now

Comment: Good. You're welcome!